# Prove that there is an infinite number of pairs $x$ and $y$ that satisfy $x+y=203$, and $\gcd(x,y)=7$

Tags: number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I have a question.

Prove that there is an infinite number of pairs $x$ and $y$ that satisfy $$x+y=203, \text{ and } \gcd(x,y)=7$$

---

If $\gcd(x,y)=7$, then $x=7p$, and $y=7q$.

then $$203=x+y=7(p+q)$$
$7$ divide $203$.

Hence such integers exist, but, how can I prove  are infinite?

I could try with $\gcd(x,203-x)=7$.

Comment: What happens if you start with one solution and then add $7$ to $x$ while subtracting $7$ from $y$?

Comment: @GregMartin This is a good idea, but it's not guaranteed that the GCD of the resulting pair will still be 7. It could end up being bigger than 7 - consider for instance the solution pair (x,y)=(-7,210) with gcd(x,y)=7, which becomes (x+7,y-7)=(0,203) with gcd(x+7,y-7)=203. Or, if you object to GCDs involving zero, consider (x,y) = (399,-196).

Comment: Good point, but we can rescue it, using $\gcd(x+7m,y-7m) = \gcd(x+7m,y-7m+x+7m)=\gcd(x+7m,203)$.

Comment: The word "infinite" implies that $x$ and $y$ must be allowed to be negative, because there are only finitely many pairs of **nonnegative** integers that add to $203$.

Answer (score 2):

Why didn't you simplify $203=x+y=7(p+q)$?

Dividing by $7$ we get $29 = p + q$. Now we are looking for $p$ and $q$ coprime.

But $\gcd(p,q) = \gcd(p,p+q) = \gcd(p,29)$, so we only have to choose $p$ coprime with $29$ (and since $29$ is prime, this is equivalent to choosing $p$ not multiple of $29$). Since $q = 29 - p$, the solutions are

$$x = 7 p$$
$$y = 7(29-p)$$

where $p$ is any number not multiple of $29$.

Answer (score 0):

If you begin with and easy example like
$\space (x,y)=(7,196),\space$ and increase or decrease one variable by any multiple of $\space 7, \space$ while doing he opposite to the other variable, then
$\quad GCD(x,y,203)=7,  \space x \ne 0\space y \ne 0.$